# How to apply a function to a pandas dataframe where two columns are the variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, methods, series

So I am trying to optimize the classification function. I have a single dataframe, but two columns that need to be processed simultaneously, not one column and then the other. Basically record[0] from column one needs to be compared to record [0] column two. Based on the classification rules, then it will output a binary code to a new column. What I have now is utilizing .items to iterate through the series', which is apparently not as efficient. I just have not been able to figure out how to use .apply or similar pandas methods to use two columns as the variables.

```
def series_compare(s1, s2):
    tmp= []
    for index, values in s1.items():
        if (values == 0) | (s2[index] == 0):
            tmp.append(0)
        elif (values == 1) | (values == 2):
            tmp.append(1)
        elif (values == 3) & (s2[index] == 4):
            tmp.append(0)
        elif (values == 3) & (s2[index] != 4):
            tmp.append(1)
        elif (values == 4) & (s2[index] == 4):
            tmp.append(0)
        elif (values == 4) & (s2[index] != 4):
            tmp.append(-99999)
        else:
            tmp.append(10)
    return(pd.Series(tmp))
```

Comment: You can use `axis=1` to feed a row into `.apply` instead of a column.  You could use something like this for your needs: `df['new_value'] = df.apply(lambda x: your_function(x['col1'], x['col2']), axis=1)`

Comment: Beautiful JAV. That made sense to me and it worked perfectly. Thank you!